# Onload first anchor link background color change

Tags: jquery, css

I am little struck, when i am loading page it is working fine and opening with first anchor link related data. week1-faith ... but Link1 "Faith" background color is not activating on Onload.
Please let me know to fix this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi add active class in first link as like this

```
<li class="link week1-faith active" rel="#faith"><a href="#week1-faith">FAITH</a></li>
```

Upadated in your js file

Add one line your file

```
$('.coda-nav > ul > li:first').addClass('active'); //**********Add This line in your js*************//
```

in `javascripts/modules.js`

```
// Script for chapters of MODULE 1
$(function() {
$('div.panel').hide();
$('.coda-nav > ul > li:first').addClass('active'); //**********Add This line in your js*************//
$('div.panel:first').addClass('active').show(); // Keeps the first one on
$('li.link').click(function() { // When an item is clicked
```

Comment: Already class in <li rel="#faith" class="link week1-faith"><a href="#week1-faith">FAITH</a></li>. If i remove that class refresh functionality will lost. Any way i have added by removing previous class and added ur code but when i am clicking another link first one is still active

Comment: I have update my answer now you can define your li class active as like this to see above

Comment: Hi Rohit, your updated code works fine to me, but when i am refreshing  page that background color not coming of that first link

Comment: @ThirupathiVemula add to one line in your js file check to above code in updated by me ...

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. and works fine..And alos one issue with this..When i am clicking other link then came to first link and refresh then background color not coming again.............

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
(function($){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('a[href$='+ hash +']').addClass('active');
})(jQuery);
```

Then in your css have active to change the background.

I've tried the selector in your page and is working good :)

Answer (score 0):

am not so good at css but

you have this css

```
.coda-nav ul li.active a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #287ED6;
    color: #EDEDED;
}
```

**and this**

```
#leftmenu ul li {
    height: 143px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 143px;
}
#leftmenu ul li a:link, a:hover, a:visited, a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #666666;
}
```

i think there is **overwriting** css's
so suggest to solve this issue by css or javascript

```
e.g element.className = 'newClassName';
```

[Link JavaScript tutorial - DOM CSS](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domcss)

**UPDATE:**

and to make sure what is happening ,and what are you doing
use **getComputedStyle** method  in the link see the examples

Answer (score 0):

if you want to after reload your page background color change of `archer tab` `<a>` then 
use this code.

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if ((window.location.pathname.indexOf($(this).attr('href'))) > -1) {
        $(this).addClass('activeMenuItem');
    }
});
```